# L298N motor controller voltages are weird

Tags: raspberry-pi-pico, motordriver

I have a Pi Pico hooked up to an L298N motor controller, -- all of it, i.e. IN1, IN2, ENA, IN3, IN4, ENB.  And all is well up to a point; the voltage across OUT1 & OUT2 (going to one motor), likewise across OUT3 & OUT4 (going to the other motor), are as expected.

The trouble is that when I turn off one of the motors, its OUT pins are not at ground, but about the voltage I'm applying to the L298N's "5V" pin (the one in the bank of three terminal block connectors the other two of which are for ground and 12V).

This would not be a problem if I was driving two independent motors.  Unfortunately what I'm doing with the L298N is powering the rails of a model train layout.  The trains draw their power from the rails, and that would be fine too except that there are places where one set of tracks intersects another (or merges into another) and where that happens it's essential for all the rails' grounds to be the same.

Is this the expected behavior of an L298N motor controller?  If it isn't, then that's a sign that the Micropython code I wrote for the Pico is wrong.  But if it is expected behavior, can anyone think of a way out?

--------- new material added after reading David C. Rankin's comments -------

D-oh!  I misunderstood what the "EN-5V jumper" meant.  So thanks.  But now (with
a fresh, undamaged motor controller in place) I think this is a software issue now (and therefore appropriate for this StackExchange).  In brief: I've found that trying to control the L298N with three pins -- IN1&IN2 for the direction, and ENA for PWM -- gives crazy results (the ones I mentioned regarding inconsistent ground voltages).  And that the solution is to put the jumper back on ENA, and apply PWM to IN1 (or IN2, according to the desired motor direction).  This solution, as it happens, appears to be the way the gpiozero module (unfortunately, available only on the "big" Raspberry Pis, not the Pico) does motor control.

Here's my code, written to make it easy to switch between the three-pin method (which gave me my weird results) and the two-pin "gpiozero" method (which is working perfectly), in case anyone besides me cares to experiment:

```py
    #
    # Micropython code -- part of a RPi Pico's main.py.
    #
    from machine import Pin, PWM

    # Can switch from PWM to plain old Pin
    class MyPWM:
        # public
        def __init__(self, pin_num):
            self.pin_num = pin_num
            self.pin = Pin(pin_num, Pin.OUT) # default -- will change
    
        def logical_off(self):
            if type(self.pin) == PWM:
                self.pwm2pin()
            self.pin.off()
        def logical_on(self):
            if type(self.pin) == PWM:
                self.pwm2pin()
            self.pin.on()
    
        def pulsate(self, duty):
            if not 0 <= duty <= 1:
                raise Exception('duty must be on [0,1]')
            if type(self.pin) == Pin:
                self.pin2pwm()
            self.pin.duty_u16(int((pow(2,16)-1)*duty))
    
        # private
        def pin2pwm(self):
            self.pin.off()
            self.pin = PWM(self.pin)
            self.pin.freq(1000)
        def pwm2pin(self):
            self.pin.duty_u16(0)
            self.pin.deinit()
            self.pin = Pin(self.pin_num, Pin.OUT)
    
    class MyDCMotor:
        def __init__(self, *, mode, fwd_pin_num, bk_pin_num, en_pin_num=None):
            # argument validation
            if not mode in ('two_pin_pwm', 'two_pin_logical', 'three_pin'):
                raise Exception('Invalid MyDCMotor mode "' + mode + '"')
    
            self.mode = mode
            self.fwd_pin_num = fwd_pin_num
            self.fwd_pin = MyPWM(fwd_pin_num)
            self.bk_pin_num = bk_pin_num
            self.bk_pin = MyPWM(bk_pin_num)
            self.en_pin_num = en_pin_num
            self.en_pin = MyPWM(en_pin_num)
    
        def drive(self, *, direction, speed):
            if not 0 <= speed <= 1.0:
                print('Error: speed must be within [0,1].')
        if direction == 'forward':
            if self.mode == 'two_pin_pwm':
                self.bk_pin.logical_off()
                self.fwd_pin.pulsate(speed)
            else:
                self.bk_pin.logical_off()
                self.fwd_pin.logical_on()
                if self.mode == 'three_pin':
                    self.en_pin.pulsate(speed)
        elif direction == 'backward':
            if self.mode == 'two_pin_pwm':
                self.fwd_pin.logical_off()
                self.bk_pin.pulsate(speed)
            else:
                self.fwd_pin.logical_off()
                self.bk_pin.logical_on()
                if self.mode == 'three_pin':
                    self.en_pin.pulsate(speed)
        elif direction == 'stop':
            self.fwd_pin.logical_off()
            self.bk_pin.logical_off()
        else:
            raise Exception('Invalid direction: ' + direction)
    
        def forward(self, *, speed):
            self.drive(direction='forward', speed=speed)
        def backward(self, *, speed):
            self.drive(direction='backward', speed=speed)
        def stop(self):
            self.drive(direction='stop', speed=0)
    
    g_dcmotor = (MyDCMotor(mode='two_pin_pwm',
                   fwd_pin_num=12, bk_pin_num=13, en_pin_num=11),
                 MyDCMotor(mode='two_pin_pwm',
                   fwd_pin_num=19, bk_pin_num=18, en_pin_num=20))
```

Comment: You have a good question, but have posted to the wrong StackExchange site. This question should be on [Electronics StackExchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). You mention the 5V input of the 3 pin terminal 12V, 5V, Gnd. That is troubling. If you have a 12V input also, you have likely toasted that L298N unless you have removed the jumper next to that pin-block. (the L298N provides internal regulation to generate the 5V input from the 12V pin). Delete here and ask on the other site.

Comment: (I know the toast issue from experience ...) Good thing the L298N controllers are cheap -- I bought a 4-pack as a replacement just in case `:)` I found [Interface L298N DC Motor Driver Module with Arduino](https://lastminuteengineers.com/l298n-dc-stepper-driver-arduino-tutorial/) useful. See the WARNING under the **On-board 5V Regulator and Jumper** section (big blue box)

Comment: Okay, good update. If you read the article, you have all the pin assignments. `IN1`, `IN2` (direction control motor A, `0,0` - off `0,1` - rev, `1,0` - fwd, `1,1` - off) The `ENA` jumper must be removed for PWM control. With the jumper in place, it is just applying 100% Duty-Cycle. (same applies to motor B pins). To use PWM, you must remove the jump and put your PWM duty-cycle output to the `ENA` pin (top  / other jumper pin is unused). ABOVE ALL, you must have a COMMON GROUND Pico, L298N and you Power Supply or weird spurious voltages are possible.

Comment: I'll look though your code -- though I write in C, so MicroPython isn't my forte, but I'll see if I can discern anything wonky. I simply used a 10K pot to set the PWM level (split the range, so `49% -> 0` controlled reverse and `51% -> 100%` was forward w/`1%` dead band in middle) I just used `adc_read()` to read current potentiometer voltage and then compared to `50%` and set `IN1/IN2` accordingly and converted the voltage to a duty-cycle on the PWM pin. The pot dial worked like a joystick on a RC remote more or less. But worked fine. Had 256 PWM steps (128 each way)

Comment: After looking over your code -- I cannot even hazard a guess at the python.  The only thing that stood out to me was the `speed` parameter and wondering where it came from and whether it was being provided in the right scale. I see your validation `if not 0 <= speed <= 1.0:`, I just don't know whether that is correct (could be 100% okay)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was unaware of the fact not all the Pi Pico's PWM pins are actually independent.  Specifically, the track that was exhibiting the strange behavior was under the control of a PWM pin that was, under the hood, the same as the PWM pin I was using to control another (third, unmentioned in my description above) track.  Everyone who plans to use the Pi Pico's PWM functionality should read up on its "PWM slices".  In a nutshell, though there are about 26 pins you can use for PWM, the total number of fully independent PWM pins is only eight (or sixteen if you're ok with quasi-independence).